# Django mysql database display data from more than one table in a for loop in template problem

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a old league web site php script with mysql database from 2006. This script not running depends to old php and mysql versions. Thats why I tried to get data from mysql database using django but I have a problem with match listing page.

At database there is a table for league matches. I can fetch data and listing from using django template system like this :

**models.py**

```
 class LeagueMatch(models.Model):
objects = None
idm = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
league = models.IntegerField()
ids = models.PositiveIntegerField()
judge = models.PositiveIntegerField()
date = models.IntegerField()
idg = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
pos = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
rnd = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
idc1 = models.IntegerField()
idc2 = models.IntegerField()
type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
idpt = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
points1 = models.IntegerField()
points2 = models.IntegerField()
frags1 = models.SmallIntegerField()
frags2 = models.SmallIntegerField()
win1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
draw = models.PositiveIntegerField()
win2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
maps = models.CharField(max_length=70)
scores = models.CharField(max_length=70)
descr = models.TextField()
server = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

```
def all_matches(request):
match_list = LeagueMatch.objects.all()
return render(request, 'home_match.html',
              {'match_list': match_list})

{% for match in match_list reversed %}
{% if match.league == 1 %}
        <div class="card" >
              <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'match-detail' match.pk %}"> Match  No {{ match.idm }} - Team A ({{ match.idc1 }}) vs Team B ({{ match.idc2 }})</a></h5>
                <p class="card-text"><b>Score : {{ match.win1 }} : {{ match.win2 }}</b></p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </br></br>
{% endif %}
```

{% endfor %}

[league matches table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bB7.png)

Template render results like this :

> All Matches
>
> ```
> Match No 55 - Team A (9) vs Team B (7)
>
> Score : 1 : 2
>
>
> Match No 53 - Team A (9) vs Team B (2)
>
> Score : 2 : 0
> ```

This is ok but team names are not in same table (league_match), there is only team number (idc1 and idc2). Team names are stored in another table name is league_clan. I want to display all matches list like this :

> ```
> Match No 55 - Team A (team 9's name ) vs Team B (team 7'name)
>
> Score : 1 : 2
> ```

I mean idc1 == 9 we will take data from other table what is the team number 9's name and display. How can I write a model or template code for this display? I couldn't do that with in {% for %} codes. Somethings wrong, need help. I hope explained thank you.

[teams table with names(tags)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA1Sr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Convert idc1 & idc2 from integerfield to ForeignKey field and then you can get the name by {{match.idc1.name}} and if it gets slow, you can use select_related.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you but getting errors like this :

OperationalError at /matches/

(1054, "Unknown column 'league_match.idc1_id' in 'field list'")

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/matches/
Django Version:     3.2.2
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:

(1054, "Unknown column 'league_match.idc1_id' in 'field list'")

Exception Location:     /home/tolga/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py, line 259, in query
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.8.5
Python Path:

['/home/tolga/q2ligi2006',
'/usr/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/home/tolga/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 03 Jun 2021 09:16:13 +0000

I updated models with ForeignKey field like this :

```
class LeagueMatch(models.Model):
objects = None
idm = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
league = models.IntegerField()
ids = models.PositiveIntegerField()
judge = models.PositiveIntegerField()
date = models.IntegerField()
idg = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
pos = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
rnd = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
idc1 = models.ForeignKey(LeagueClan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teama')
idc2 = models.ForeignKey(LeagueClan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teamb')
type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
idpt = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
points1 = models.IntegerField()
points2 = models.IntegerField()
frags1 = models.SmallIntegerField()
frags2 = models.SmallIntegerField()
win1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
draw = models.PositiveIntegerField()
win2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
maps = models.CharField(max_length=70)
scores = models.CharField(max_length=70)
descr = models.TextField()
server = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

what is wrong thank you?